# Lock file by one process

Tags: c#, .net, process, file-locking

I have an application which runs multiple processes at the same time for reading and writing to file.

```
private Process PrepareProcess(string workingDirName, string scriptPath, string[] args) {
    var process = new Process {
        StartInfo = {
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirName,
            FileName = scriptPath,
            Arguments = string.Format(string.Join(" ", args))
        }
    };
    return process;
}
```

I need to be sure that file will be modified only by one process at a time. How can I do that?

The process will run an external script which will the modify file. I can't manage to open the file. I need to manage running process.

Comment: One file can not be modified by multiple process simultaneously. If this happens you will get an exception.

Comment: @Muctadir That's not true. See `FileShare.Write` or `FileShare.ReadWrite`

Comment: Is it yours process that you are starting (with sources you own) or some external third-party one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "Named Mutex". It helps you to say "Hey wait, am working on with that file!". It is your call you can wait or ignore that file.

Take a look at [Mutex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also worth noting that by default if you open a file, `FileShare` will be `None` which means *don't share access with anyone till I close the file*. So it will fail when attempt to access in another process. You can't modify it simultaneously. To prevent that failure and handling exception and all using "Mutex" is a elegant way.

Answer (score 3):

Pass [`FileShare.None`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) to `File.Open` when you open the file.

That will block any attempts for multiple processes to write to the file simulataneously. The downside is that if a process attempts to open the file when another process already has it open, then the second attempt will fail. If that's a problem then you will probably need to use a mutex to serialize access. The advantage of using a mutex is that it allows the second process to block and wait until the file is available.